# How can we install the Solana CLI when we get the below error?

Tags: solana

I hope you are all well.
I don't manage to install the Solana CLI. In the documentation they say we have to use
this command:

```
curl https://release.solana.com/v1.14.3/solana-install-init-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.exe --output C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe --create-dirs
```

but my OS(windows 10) shows this error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest: Could not find a positional parameter accepting the '--output' argument.
```

Could you help me please?

Thank you very much

Take care

Pierre

Answer (score 0):

You are perhaps trying to install the it using PowerShell. Try installing via the windows cmd or git bash.

Comment: Alternatively you can add ```cmd /c``` before the command in PowerShell  so the command will be:

```cmd /c curl https://release.solana.com/v1.14.3/solana-install-init-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.exe --output C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe --create-dirs```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open cmd as an administrator.
2. Run `curl https://release.solana.com/v1.9.14/solana-install-init-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.exe --output C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe --create-dirs`
3. Run `C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe v1.9.14`

NB: I have used **v1.9.14** the solana's github shows only **v1.9** are compatible with windows.

Comment: @Pierre, if it has helped out don't forget to upvote.